# To show that $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}[-n,n]=\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

We are asked to show that $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}[-n,n]=\mathbb{R}$. This is in the context of families of sets. We have previously covered proofs, sets and boolean operators. I've managed to use one of the definitions of families of sets provided in the book to obtain that:

$$
\bigcup_{n\in N}[-n,n]=\{x:x \textrm{ belongs to at least one set} \{x\in \mathbb{R}:-n\leq x \leq n\}\}.
$$

My attempts of a proof suffers from a lack of tools i think. But i think it is obvious why the union equals $\mathbb{R}$ because if one consider that one of the sets is $[-\infty,\infty]$, then x must be in all of the smaller sets. Any ideas for making this a rigorous proof?

Comment: None of those sets is $[\infty,\infty]$ (and $\infty$ isn't a number).

Comment: I agree with your comment, but what i meant is that there is always a larger set such that all the smaller set are included.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}$ is a whole space, hence one direction of inclusion is obvious, namely $$\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [-n, n] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$$

The other direction. Pick $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and show it belongs to some interval, for example to $[-\lceil|x|\rceil, \lceil|x|\rceil]$.

Comment: As you said, the inclusion in one direction is obvious. My attempt at the other one is:

Assume $x\in \mathbb{R}$. We can always find an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq \lceil |x| \rceil$. Then $x\in [-n,n]$. This process can be repeated for any x, which results in x always being in at least one of these intervals.

Comment: So the sets are equal.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in \mathbb R$, then, by the Archimedean property of the reals, there is $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $|x| \le n$, hence $x \in [-n,n]$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Im not sure about whether or not we should consider this property to be known at the present time in the course. But i get the idea, so my non-rigorous attempt at a proof would be that: Since we can show that $x\in[-n,n]$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and we can always find a natural number larger than this, then this would cover the entire real line.

Comment: @FredW If you show that every real $x$ is in some $[-n,n]$, then by definition of the union you are already done. Because then $x$ is in the union and that is precisely what you wanted to show.